# Automtically get drop down in extJS tagfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there any way by which my dropdown arrow of tagfield can automatically get clicked. Here is my fiddle, I want As soon as I load the page MY drop down get clicked.

My fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/219s

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the physical click, only the resulting open menu, the [`pickerfield`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Picker.html) provides a function [`expand`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Picker.html#method-expand) that opens the picker menu. You can call it from the [`afterrender`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Picker.html#event-afterrender) event, for example:

```
listeners:{
    afterrender: function(tagfield) {
        tagfield.expand();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
   "$(".x-form-arrow-trigger").click()"
```

to work you need to use jquery.

if youre not using jquery, you can do it with the JS version aswell:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("x-form-arrow-trigger").click();
```

a good idea would be to call it inside a "onload function" like this

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("x-form-arrow-trigger").click();
};
```

so the dropdown button gets clicked when the window's load event fires.

Comment: Exactly. I am doing on window.load it selef. Now The problem which I am facing is on my window there are 4 or 5 tagfields are there so after this code `document.getElementsByClassName("x-form-arrow-trigger")` I am getting array and in array[0].click is not working.

Comment: if you have multiple tagfields which all have the same classes, you could just add a different class to each one "tagfield1" "tagfield2" ... and then call the click event on the class or classes you want to open. iam not sure what you meant by the above comment, so tell me if iam way off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(".x-form-arrow-trigger").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This I need to write in my JS file right after my condition. Also getting `$ ` is not defined.

Comment: inlude jquery to your project

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an operation after loading the document, you have several options in ExtJs:

#### Ext.onReady

You can pass a function to [`Ext.onReady`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.html#method-onReady). This callback functions are executed after the document is loaded.

```
Ext.onReady( () => {
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tagfield:first').pop().expand();    
});
```

#### Event-Listener

Another option is to use the [`afterrending`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#event-afterrender) event.

```
tagfieldInstance.on('afterrender', (cmp) => cmp.expand());

//or

{
    xtype: 'tagfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
    store: shows,
    displayField: 'show',
    valueField: 'id',
    queryMode: 'local',
    filterPickList: true,
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (cmp) {
            cmp.expand();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try onTriggerClick here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21ct)